# working with stored dates and sysdates in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that returns all the products in inventory that have been sitting there for more than 30 days.

the query I'm trying to write is this.. return all product that has a delivery_date more than 30 days ago.

this is what i have so far.. but i don't think its the right way.

```
select product_id, stock_lvl, delivery_date
  from inventory
  where select trunc(sysdate) - ?????? > 30
  order by product_id;
```

Comment: Is your date value a column in "inventory" table ?

Comment: yes, it is. i have a delivery date as part of the inventory table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can go simpler:

```
select * from inventory where inv_input_dt < sysdate - 30
```

here are advantages:

1. You may have an index on inventory_input_date and it could be used by DB. It could NOT be used when you have some calculation on a column, like "inv_input_dt - sysdate > 30"
2. "sysdate - 30" is calculated only once, versus some calculation for every record in a table